# Really installed packages in (K)ubuntu

Tags: package-management

1) First question

How to list **really** installed packages in ubuntu?

The problem of `dpkg --get-selections` (the command written in almost any forum) is that its second column (which is `install` / `deinstall`) completely depends on previously issued commands (I mean `dpkg --set-selections` and `dpkg --clear-selections`), but not on actual state of package (installed or not).

2) Second question

I (investigating described above problem) semi-occasionally executed command - `dpkg --clear-selections`, and now have almost all packages in `deinstall` state. So how can I update states of packages (and make them consistent with those states, which `aptitude show <pkg_name>` outputs)?

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions in a single post, split them into separate ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of installed packages, run this:

```
dpkg -l | grep -c ^.i
```

`dpkg -l` will list all available packages and the first field consists of status codes. Specifically (from `man dpkg`):

```
The  first  three columns of the output show the desired action,
the package status, and errors, in that order.

Desired action:
 u = Unknown
 i = Install
 h = Hold
 r = Remove
 p = Purge

Package status:
 n = Not-installed
 c = Config-files
 H = Half-installed
 U = Unpacked
 F = Half-configured
 W = Triggers-awaiting
 t = Triggers-pending
 i = Installed

Error flags:
  <empty> = (none)
  R = Reinst-required
```

So, lines whose 2nd character is `i` describe installed packages. So, passing the output through `grep -c ^.i` will return the number of lines whose 2nd char is `i`, which will be the number of packages you currently have installed.

Comment: It seems that it also does not work.
Your approach gives 153 installed packages (what is very small):
`$ dpkg -l | grep -c ^ii`
`153`

`dpkg --get-selections` approach givees 159 installed packages
`$ dpkg --get-selections  | grep "\binstall" | wc -l`
`159`

And, most important
`dpkg -l | grep  ^ii | grep kile` gives no output, but
`$ aptitude show kile`
`Package: kile  `                          
`State: installed`
`Automatically installed: no`

Comment: @Void The difference between `dpkg -l` and `dpkg --get-selections` is normal, that's because `--get-selections` is not listing installed packages but the list package selections. You can see what the differences are exactly by saving both outputs to files and running `diff` on them. The issue with `aptitude` is indeed a problem. That is very strange, looking into it now.

Comment: All that I wrote above but in more readable form [link](http://pastebin.com/v7VH04mF)

Comment: @Void OK, that's just weird. What system are you running? Is this a normal install? You seem to have something strange. On my Debian, both `dpkg -l | grep -c ^ii` and the `--get-selections` approach return the same number of packages and I can't reproduce your issue with `kile`. I am guessing the differences of the `--get-selections` is because of your `--clear-selections` but I still can't understand why `dpkg` and `aptitude` return different outputs, they search the same database!

Comment: Kubuntu 14.04 (updated when it was in "alpha")

Comment: It seems I figured out...
According to dpkg-query [man](http://pastebin.com/ikM40ybd), I should not grep only by `ii`, but by `"^[[:alnum:]]i"`, and in particular `$ dpkg -l | grep kile` gives `ri  kile`

Comment: @Void yes? So what was it? Why was is aptitude giving different results?

Comment: According to dpkg-query [man](http://pastebin.com/ikM40ybd), I should not grep only by `ii`, but by `"^[[:alnum:]]i"`, and in particular `$ dpkg -l | grep kile` gives `ri  kile...`
And overall number of installed packages now is better: `$ dpkg -l | grep -P "^[[:alnum:]]i" | wc -l
2844`

Comment: @Void ah, I see, that makes sense. I edited my answer, thanks for the info :)